# Android redirect does not work

Tags: javascript, android

I need to redirect in a javascript file to a given URI specified by the user.

So a quick example how I do this:

```
function redirect(uri) {
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
    document.location.href=uri;      
  }
  window.location.replace(uri);
}
```

This works fine for everything except Android devices. iOS and all modern Webbrowsers support window.location.replace(...), however Android devices don't do that.

But if I now try to redirect using this function, lets say to "http://www.google.com" the android devices fail to actually redirect to the given url.

Now is it just me being stupid here right now or is there another problem?

Sincerly

p.s. the redirect function is called as an callback from an XML request sent, but that should not be an issue at all.

Comment: Android 4.0 supports it :>

Comment: webview code please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Android supports `document.location` without the `href` property

Try to use:

```
function redirect(uri) {
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) 
    document.location=uri;      
  else
    window.location.replace(uri);
}
```

Comment: This solution works for redirecting android. However, after some hours of debugging my problem did not come from the redirect but from an other problem. Well, still giving bounty to you for your working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `window.location.href`, not `document.location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest :

```
location.assign('someUrl');
```

It's a better solution as it keeps history of the original document, so you can navigate to the previous webpage using back-button or history.back() as explained [here.](http://www.frontbackend.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-location-replace-and-location-href)

Answer (score 0):

You can use match and replace in iOS but apparently not in Android. In my experience this is what works for redirects in Android:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
        document.location = "http://www.your URL/your HTML file.html";
    } // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use: `window.location = "http://example.com";`