# window.location updates don't trigger onNavigationStateChange?

Tags: android-webview, react-native

I'm working on an early prototype for a hybrid app, eventually it will be using more React Native components but at this point it's just a WebView.

I'm using the example code from Facebook's documentation, but it seems like `window.location` JS updates inside the WebView aren't triggering the onNavigationStateChange callback.

I have the component in my render function:

```
<WebView
  ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  style={styles.webView}
  url={this.state.url}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
  startInLoadingState={true}
  scalesPageToFit={this.state.scalesPageToFit}
/>
```

And a method to update the state on navigation change:

```
onNavigationStateChange: function(navState) {
  this.setState({
    backButtonEnabled: navState.canGoBack,
    forwardButtonEnabled: navState.canGoForward,
    url: navState.url,
    status: navState.title,
    loading: navState.loading,
    scalesPageToFit: true
  });
}
```

The page I'm loading tries `window.location.replace()` or assigning `window.location.href` directly:

```
if (window.location.replace){ 
  window.location.replace(url);
} else {
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858199/android-redirect-does-not-work) which says window.location.replace doesn't work in Android, but shouldn't the `window.location.href` assignment go through? When I set a breakpoint inside the onNavigationStateChange method, it never receives a navState corresponding to the updated URL, which means the WebView never redirects, it just sits there at the originally loaded URL.

I can try to rework this to not need the redirect but it's coming from a site I don't have control over (Salesforce), so I was hoping to find a solution within the React Native component. Any suggestions would be super helpful!